# How to map 3 objects to a view model with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm using Asp.NET Core 2.2. I have two domain models called **Product** and **ProductType**

This is **Product** domain model

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductImage { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductTypeID")]
    public virtual ProductType ProductType{ get; set; }
}
```

And this is **ProductType** domain model

```
public class ProductType
{
    public int ProductTypeID { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeName { get; set; }
    public string ProductTypeImage { get; set; }
    public string ProductTypeDescription { get; set; 
}
```

I want to map them their DTOs using Automapper
This is ProductTypeDTO

```
public class ProductTypeDTO
{
    public int ProductTypeName { get; set; }
    public string ProductTypeImage { get; set; }
}
```

And the same properties for Product Domain model and ProductDTO.
Then I have a View model in which I hold a Enumrable of these DTOs so

this is **CarViewModel**

```
public class CarViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductTypeDTO> ProductTypeDTO { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductDTO> ProductDTO { get; set; }
}
```

The main problem is, I don't know how to create a map between domain models and  DTOs and then **merge** DTOs into CarViewModel. This is representation of what I want to do
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have write some code. it's help you,

Step1 : create automapper profile

```
public  class AutoMapperConfig : Profile
 {
  public   AutoMapperConfig()
    {
    AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
       cfg.CreateMap<Product, ProductDTO>();
       cfg.CreateMap<ProductType, ProductTypeDTO>();
        /* etc */
     });
     }
   }
```

Step2: Configure in start up

```
 public class Startup
{
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{


    // Start Registering and Initializing AutoMapper

    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperConfig>());
    services.AddAutoMapper();


}
 }
```

Step 3. Get Output.

```
     var carViewModel=new CarViewModel{
             ProductDTO = ProductQuery.ToList().Select(x=>    AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ProductDTO>(Product)).ToList(),
        ProductTypeDTO = ProductTypeQuery.ToList().Select(x=>   AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ProductTypeDTO>(Product)).ToList(),
       };
```